# Dot product of two cross products in $\Bbb R^3$ with general metric

Tags: riemannian-geometry, 3d, cross-product

I would like to find the generalized formula of the identity $$(A\times B).(C\times D)=(A\cdot C)(B\cdot D)-(A\cdot D)(B\cdot C)$$ which holds in an Euclidian metric, within a general metric $g$ on $\Bbb R^3$.

Thanks for any help, I wish a nice evening.

Comment: What does the Euclidean metric have to do with the identity you've given?

Answer (score 2):

This has a metric independent generalization in Geometric algebra (or Clifford Algebra) as follows

$$-(A\wedge B)\cdot(C\wedge D)=(A\cdot C)(B\cdot D)-(A\cdot D)(B\cdot C),$$

where the dot product of the bivectors indicates the scalar grade selection.  This identity holds in $\Bbb R^n$, or in non-Eucliean generalizations.

The metric dependencies are all in the vector dot products.  For example, with a basis and reciprocal basis, a vector $A$ can be written

$$A = \gamma_\mu a^\mu = \gamma^\mu a_\mu.$$

The dot product is:

$$A^2 = A \cdot A = a_\mu a_\nu g^{\mu\nu},$$

where

$$g^{\mu\nu} = \gamma^\mu \cdot \gamma^\nu.$$

In the distribution identity above, the wedge product is an antisymmetric sum of vectors:

$$A \wedge B = \frac{1}{2} ( A B - B A ).$$

This quantity is referred to as a bivector in Geometric Algebra (and in an Euclidean $\Bbb R^3$ space is the dual of the cross product).

Comment: It could be noted that the cross product itself is metrical, but since there were two cross products in the given expression, the metric dependences from those cross products cancel out, leaving only the leading minus sign here.